# How to disable a specific delete button in grocery_crud

Tags: codeigniter-3, grocery-crud, ion-auth

In my user management page, I want to disable the delete button of my super admin account so that it can't be deleted. I used ion_auth for authentication and grocery_crud for my crud functions. How can I accomplish that? Any help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced same problem and there is one quick that i know .

make superadmin userid 1 and in php part check if userid = 1 like this

```
$user_id = $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
if($user_id == 1){
// this is superadmin do not delete
}else{
// your delete functions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try this.